# python - easy_install stops working after distribute upgrade

Tags: python, easy-install

When trying to install a package easy_install asked me to upgrade distribute:

```
The required version of distribute (>=0.6.35) is not available,
and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
install a more recent version first, using
'easy_install -U distribute'.
```

This seemed to work fine:

```
$ easy_install -U distribute
Searching for distribute
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/distribute/
Best match: distribute 0.7.3
Processing distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg
Removing distribute 0.6.28 from easy-install.pth file
Adding distribute 0.7.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using /xxx/software/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for distribute
Finished processing dependencies for distribute
```

But now when I start easy_install I get this:

```
$ easy_install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xx/software/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/xx/software/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.6-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/xx/software/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.6-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2393, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'easy_install') not found
```

What happened? How do I fix this

Comment: Is it critical for you to use ``easy_install`` and not ``pip``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try updating your setup tools manually.**

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py
sudo python ez_setup.py --user
```

Answer (score 2):

Following an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13576163/256798) on a different question about pip vs. easy_install, you can uninstall a package that was installed with easy_install using pip:

```
sudo pip uninstall distribute
```

This removed the offending version of distribute, and easy_install works again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, then i found that there is easy_install-2.7 and I can install packages properly.