# Python Window Closes Can't Read Output

Tags: python, windows

I am attempting to install a python module using

```
python setup.py install
```

in Windows 7 32 bit.

I start up cmd.exe, navigate to the module source and run the command. This brings up the UAC window, then opens a NEW console window which closes. I don't think the install is working as I can't find the module in lib/site-packages.

I've read a few similar questions but they ALL say the same thing, run it from Windows command prompt. I am doing this... it's still bringing up a new window. TIA

Comment: OMG, I'm an idiot I thought running it as ADMIN was messing up the ENV, but it turns out you need the setuptools package to use setup.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you succceded but in the future you might want to use the easy install tool it for:

> Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python
>   packages

The idea is that it will automatically look for the package download and install it for example:

```
easy_install SQLObject
```

will install SQLObject module on your PC and add it to the site  packages

Download link:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/1.1.6#installation-instructions

one more option is to use pip, you can see a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install) here and decide what you want.