# Python, Ubuntu: Install PyPi package for a specific Python version

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.3, easy-install, pypi

I've installed Python 3.3 alongside Python 2.75 on my Ubuntu machine. The problem is that `easy_install` gets packages for the default, 2.75 version only, e.g:

```
easy_install pymongo

$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymongo
>>>
```

But:

```
$ python3.3
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:30:32) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymongo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

ImportError: No module named 'pymongo'
```

How can I install PyPi packages for the Python 3.3 installation?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use [`pip` over `easy_install`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install).

Comment: @hcwhsa What makes it better?

Comment: Have you read the answers on the linked question?

Comment: Sorry, thought they were separate links to `pip` and `easy_install` sites. Will read, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `easy_install3`.  In apt-get you get it by

```
apt-get install python3-setuptools
```