# Simple instructions for installing python easy_install on OSX

Tags: python, macos, easy-install

I'm a front-end developer with zero server-side experience. I'm trying to learn a little python for an app I'm building, and I literally cannot find anywhere that makes it easy to install easy_install. Everything I read is full of lingo I don't get, like using homebrew or PATHs. And pypi.python.org is TERRIBLY written and designed. So far it's only sent me in circles.

I'm looking for a simple set of instructions in the following format:

1. Go to x website and click x link
2. Type x into the terminal and run
3. Type x to be sure it's installed properly

Please for the benefit of myself and the whole internet, can someone provide this? I'm definitely up for learning how to do some things the hard way, but Python isn't something I need to know very thoroughly right now, and I imagine that's the case for others just looking to get their feet wet.

Assume I have Python installed, but not that I know anything else about using it.

(If there really is a resource out there like this that exists, let me know... I just haven't seen anything like it yet and I've been googling around for about an hour.)

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Python deployment... ;)

Comment: I'm just a fan of the irony in the title.

Comment: @WesHardaker i know, right? I hesitated to even ask.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need `easy_install`, or would `pip` work? `pip` is more up-to-date, and includes (among other things) the ability to uninstall packages, which `easy_install` can't do.

Comment: the book I'm reading, "Mining the Social Web" by Matthew Russell, recommends it and refers to it often. So, do you know of where I could find these sorts of instructions for installing pip?

Comment: @BryceJohnson: The [`pip` home page](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html). Almost, remember that most books are at least a couple years out of date by the time you read them, which is a long time in the software development world, so you will need to learn to verify things online before you trust them. (And remember that blog posts can go out of date too. The web is filled with blogs for working around all the problems with Python in OS X 10.5 that look scary as hell, but are completely meaningless to you on 10.7-10.9…)

Comment: thank you! I hope many find your instructions as useful as I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`easy_install` is part of [`setuptools`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/). For a while, `distribute` was a separate fork of `setuptools` that included its own `easy_install`, and you had to put a bit of thought into which one you wanted, but that's no longer an issue; the two have merged back into one project. So, the question is, how do you get `setuptools`?

---

- If you're using Apple's pre-installed versions of Python, you already *have* `setuptools`, with a working `easy_install`, for all versions. You can also use `easy_install-2.5`, etc., for the earlier versions of Python that Apple also pre-installs. So there's nothing to do.
- If you're using a Homebrew Python, it automatically installs `setuptools` by default, so again, nothing to do.
- If you're using a third-party package manager that doesn't automatically install `setuptools` (as at least was true for MacPorts last time I checked), it probably has its own package for `python32-setuptools` or `python32-easy-install` or something like that.
- Most of the "extra-batteries" distributions (ActiveState, Enthought, etc.) of Python similarly include `setuptools`, so again, nothing to do.

If you're using a Python.org binary, a custom-built Python with default configuration, etc., the standard `setuptools` instructions for ["Unix-based Systems including Mac OS X"](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#unix-based-systems-including-mac-os-x) work fine.

If you installed Python somewhere you don't have write access, you will need to `sudo` the installation step, as in the second variant.

So:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
```

And that's all there is to it.

---

All that being said, you almost never want to use `easy_install`, except to install two things:

- `readline`, to replace the fake libedit-based support with real libreadline-based support. (And any other packages that don't work with `pip`, but this is the only really popular one.)
- `pip`, so you never need to use `easy_install` again.

Most of the cases above that include `setuptools` also include `pip`; the one exception is Apple pre-installed Python, where `sudo easy_install pip` is the simplest way to get `pip`.

For the cases that don't come with either, the standard documentation for [installing `pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) also works:

- Install or upgrade `setuptools` (as above) if you have a version older than 0.7.
- Download [get-pip.py](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py).
- `python get-pip.py`

Again, `sudo` if you need to, and replace the `python` with `python3.3` or `python2.6` or `/opt/local/mypython/bin/python` or whatever to install for any non-default versions.

---

Finally, for upgrading, once you have any version of `pip`, and `setuptools` 0.7 or later, it's as easy as you could imagine:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

Again, `sudo` if necessary, and `pip-3.3` or whatever if necessary.

---

Note that to make `easy_install` or `pip` actually useful, you may need a compiler toolchain. The easy way to do this is to install Xcode from the Mac App Store (free as of late 2013), launch Xcode, open Preferences, go to Downloads, and install the "Command Line Tools". This is sufficient for almost everything you'd ever want to do.

The one major exception is SciPy and related packages, for which you will also need a Fortran compiler. See [this blog post for Python 2.x](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/installing-scipy-etc-with-apples-python.html) and [this one for 3.x](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/installing-scipy-etc-for-python-3-on-mac.html) for details. If all of that looks scary to you, you may be happier using Enthought or one of the other pre-packaged scientific distributions.

---

One last thing: If you installed a non-Apple Python, and then upgraded your OS X (or Homebrew or MacPorts or Enthought or …) to a newer major version (e.g., from OS X 10.8 to 10.9), you may need some extra steps. For every case but OS X itself, they should be documented on the home page for whichever package manager or Python distribution you're using. For an OS X upgrade, reinstalling your third-party Python is usually the simplest solution if you run into a problem (after first verifying that you actually *need* a third-party Python in the first place), even if it means you have to reinstall your site packages.

Comment: although I beg to differ about "Unix-based Systems Including Mac OS X" working fine, thanks for filling me on the fact that I already have easy_install :) Also, if I can find some really straightforward way to install pip, I'll do that. Thanks again!

Comment: @BryceJohnson: In what case does it not work? It has worked for me for every recent 2.x or 3.x Python.org install and standard-configured source release. If there's some case it _doesn't_ work for, that's an unexpected bug you should either file, or mail to the python-mac list.

Comment: sorry, it's not that it doesn't work, it's that it doesn't make sense to me. It's just pretty terse for a noob like me.

Comment: @BryceJohnson: I think the docs are reasonable for anyone who's gone out of their way to build a custom Python build or install a Unix-style package manager, and they're irrelevant for anyone who's just sticking with Apple's Python, so… I don't think it's really a problem. But I certainly don't speak for the python-mac community, I'm mostly just an interested user of their work, so if you disagree, you definitely should write to the list with questions or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The short correct answer is [don't use EasyInstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install).

[Use pip!](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#python-os-support)

Comment: The page has moved here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/

I wish I could edit the original post, but I can't: The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!