# Python package management in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, shell, installation

Every time I tried to install a new package for python on Mac OS X, I had this issue which these packages had different ways to setup with different package management tools. Specially for new versions of Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks, some of installers are buggy, then I needed to switch between them. I'm asking for a short description and comparison between these main command-line installers: `easy_install`, `pip`, `port`, `apt-get`, `brew`, `fink`, and etc. Of course, sometimes there is no way other than installing through source code `make install`, `python setup.py`, or `.pkg` installer files. But I guess that's not the case when you need to install more complicated packages with lots of dependencies.

What I'm asking has two sides:

1. Is it safe to use them side by side? or are there any known conflicts between these command-line tools? (at least `brew` throws warnings on `port` availability)
2. Is there any known cons and pros based on nature of these package managements, in case when we had choice between them?

Comment: it is usually recommended that you don't use two package managers side by side. I usually just stick with `pip`

Comment: It is known that it's really better to use Pip over easy_install as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install).
Another good practice is to use virtual env and pip together to avoid conflicts between differents projects. For Python projects, you don't need something else.

Comment: What about port? sometimes there are packages on https://pypi.python.org but you cannot install it with pip. or sometimes you need to use `port` with different package names. Or you find `apt-get` working for linux but same package has different name on Mac's `apt-get`.

Comment: I have also more specific questions about installers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290751/installing-matplotlib-on-mac-os-x-10-9

Answer (score 0):

1. pip and easy_install are for python libraries.
2. apt-get, brew, fink, port, etc. These tools are 'distro style' package management tools.

They have one area of overlap in terms of 'why do i need one of each?' and that is Library dependencies.

pip is the tool endorsed by the most python developers and the python packaging SIG going forward, so TLDR; use pip not easy_install

these tools also work with virtualenvs and virtualenvs are great. use them :)

You will however run into occasions where you need other libraries that python doesnt quite know what to do with when you try and build a python package with pip. It is these moments that make it necessary to have one of the other tools.