# Installing matplotlib on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, python-2.x, gtk2

As a requirement to install [OCRopus](https://code.google.com/p/ocropus/), I have successfully installed `matplotlib` on Mac OS X 10.9.1 by `pip`:

```
$ sudo pip install matplotlib
```

But after installing OCRopus the test didn't work because of laking this module: `matplotlib.backends._backend_gdk`. Reading this [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Uhcu2F-DkqDW8tFLhM6dPTG7PqikuD5bySmC27-W_3A/edit?pli=1#) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346090/importerror-no-module-named-backend-gdk) convinced me that my problems might gone if I reinstall `matplotlib` through:

```
$ sudo port install py27-matplotlib +gtk2
```

But on Mac OS X 10.9.1 it seems there is a bug which I receive this error: `Error: Dependency 'py27-pyobjc' not found.`:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for py27-matplotlib
Error: Dependency 'py27-pyobjc' not found.
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port py27-matplotlib failed
```

All I need is to install different variant of `matplotlib`. This is what I get from `port variants py27-matplotlib`:

```
$ port variants py27-matplotlib
py27-matplotlib has the variants:
   cairo: Enable Cairo backends
   dvipng: Enable dvipng support
   ghostscript: Enable GhostScript support
   gtk2: Enable GTKAgg backend
   gtk3: Enable GTK3Agg backend
   latex: Enable LaTeX support
   pdftops: Enable pdftops support
   pyside: Enable PySide backend
   qt4: Enable QT4Agg backend
[+]tkinter: Enable tkAgg backend
   universal: Build for multiple architectures
   webagg: Enable WebAgg backend
```

Any idea how to get `+gtk2` on Mac OS X 10.9.1? or how to make pip to install `matplotlib` with this particular settings?

Comment: Have you tried installing it via brew?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian not actually, because I thought it might leads to other problems. And after googling I found similar issue here in brew: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out problem was on my computer. I couldn't figure out the source of the problem. Finally, I tried out the process on a clean installed Mac OS X 10.9.1 with new Xcode command-line tools, and new MacPorts, and upgraded python 2.7.6, then it worked fine.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have the python library for objective-C installed. Did you double-check that you [installed command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools)? Then try `port install py27-pyobjc`

I recommend installing it via brew because I think it's better maintained, and it'll choose the best backend for you. I had a lot of [issues](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/issues/56) installing matplotlib, but eventually was able to get them resolved.

Cheers,
Olga

Comment: This is my ticket on macport: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/42230 if it helps. I have installed "Command Line Tools (OS X Mavericks) for Xcode - Late October 2013" manually, just like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server/19908327#19908327
Even I cannot run `port install py27-pyobjc`.

Comment: in order to use `brew` I need to remove `port`. Do you suggest me to that? :D This is another question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289974/python-package-management-in-mac-os-x

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tired brew but didn't work for me. Actually I gave up after few ties on resolving errors and warnings on `brew doctor`.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for mac: I had a similar issue in installing the matplotlib. Follow these instructions and you are done:

1. Open terminal.
2. Install python3 using brew. ( Ignore this step if you already have it) Note: To install brew:

   ```
   brew install python3
   ```
3. Install freetype:

   ```
   brew install freetype
   ```
4. Now install pkg-config using pip3:

   ```
   brew install pkg-config
   ```
5. Finally install matplotlib:

   ```
   sudo pip3 install matplotlib
   ```

It's late but I hope this helps you.