# getting DistributionNotFound error, but package exists

Tags: python, django, pyjade

I am running [pyjade](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade) for Django templates as I find it much easier to write in, but I am trying to convert it to html with the built in converter. When I run `pyjade -c django input.jade output.html` I get the error `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: six`. However, the package `six` does in fact exist, and I can import it on python, and when I run `pip install six --upgrade` it says it is already up-to-date.

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyjade", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2707, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: six
```

What would be causing this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re-install via easy_setup (vs pip) solved it for me on OS X Mavericks:

`sudo easy_install six`

Hope that helps you!

Comment: glad it seems to have worked for you, too. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install) may provide some hints as to why it failed (`easy_install` installs a binary rather than tries to build?). Still doesn't quite explain why pip says everything is peachy when it isn't...

Answer (score 4):

An old setuptools was my culprit.

`pip install -U setuptools`

Comment: well, my too .. it took a long time to find out :D thanks!