# pip fails, easy_install succeeds

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pip, easy-install

I was trying to install nose in a virtual environment today.

When trying with pip:

> pip install nose

I got this error:

> ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.5 ...

And could not get around it.

However,

> easy_install nose

Just worked and didn't throw any errors.

SO is full of comments about how easy_install is a bad idea (like: [Why use pip over easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install))

**Question:**

Is there any downside to installing packages with whatever works instead of staying 100% loyal to pip? It seems like there are packages out there that cause pip to fail but that easy_install can handle without any problem.