# Installing easy_install on Windows, change location of installation

Tags: python, easy-install

I'm trying to install `easy_install` on Windows. I don't have access to the write directories where Python is installed, but I have set my `PYTHONPATH` to be a writeable location. But when I try the command python `setup.py` I receive the error:

```
   [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python266\\Lib\\sitepackages\\test-easy-install-3464.write-test'
```

How can I set the location where `easy_install` is installed?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple solutions to this. The best in my opinion is to use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). It lets you create python environments that are separate from your system python. You can install and change packages within those environments freely, and you can have as many environments as you want. You'll use pip instead of easy_install, [which I think is recommended anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install).

You can install virtualenv into your system python on Windows from the following site:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#virtualenv