# Can't install Python-MySQL on OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: python, mysql, macos, osx-yosemite

I can't install Python-MySQL, I already tried with easy_install, pip and sources..
And I always get the same error. This is what I get:

```
Matts-MacBook:Python matt$ sudo easy_install MySQL-python
Searching for MySQL-python
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.5
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-           1.2.5.zip#md5=654f75b302db6ed8dc5a898c625e030c
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-i14rIs/MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup.cfg
Running MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-i14rIs/MySQL-    python-1.2.5/egg-dist-tmp-mG9d4K
clang: warning: -framework CrashReporterSupport: 'linker' input unused
In file included from _mysql.c:44:
/usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:349:11: warning: 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T' macro redefined
#define SIZEOF_SIZE_T  SIZEOF_LONG
      ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:56:17: note: 
  previous definition is here
#        define SIZEOF_SIZE_T           4
^In file included from _mysql.c:44:
/usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:443:9: warning: 'HAVE_WCSCOLL' macro redefined
#define HAVE_WCSCOLL
    ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:912:9: note: 
  previous definition is here
#define HAVE_WCSCOLL 1
    ^
_mysql.c:1589:10: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
  [-Wtautological-compare]
    if (how < 0 || how >= sizeof(row_converters)) {
        ~~~ ^ ~
3 warnings generated.
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.Internal.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks'
ld: framework not found CrashReporterSupport
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: As a minor point of fact, MySQL-python seems to be abandoned by the sole project owner and doesn't support Python 3 (though there are Py3-compatible forks out there). Is using the Oracle-supported [mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python) package (works with Python 2 and 3) an option?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've solved the problem as follows:

1. After installing the [OSX command line tools](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html), to install the MySQL-python.

   `$ xcode-select --install`

   `$ sudo pip install MySQL-python`

   (Three warning message is issued, but, "Successfully installed MySQL-python" ...)
2. "import MySQLdb" error from the Python interpreter("image not found" error) has been solved in the following way:

   `$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/`

My environment, "OSX Yosemite, mysql 5.6.21, Python 2.7.8".

Good luck.

Comment: This fixed the frustrating "import MySQLdb" error for me.

Comment: After upgrading MySQL to 5.7.10 from 5.6.26 on OSX Yosemite, Python 2.7.11 `sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/`

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to use `pip` instead of `easy-install`, as it's the more advanced solution. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install) for reasons.

Since you also get an XCode error you probably don't have the OSX command line tools installed. They are required for compiling `MySQL-python`. You can download them from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/opensource/) after logging in.

If you should still run into an error, install `mysql-client` via [homebrew](http://brew.sh). `brew install mysql --client-only`

Comment: Hi guys, anyone had solved this issue?  i still gets this error: "Hy guys, anyone has solved this issue?  i still got"

Answer (score 0):

Install mysql via homebrew first.For homebrew installation refer this link
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-homebrew-os-x-yosemite-10-10-package-manager-unix-apps/
then

```
pip uninstall MySQL-python
brew install mysql
pip install MySQL-python
```