# Scrapy throws ImportError: cannot import name xmlrpc_client

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

After install Scrapy via pip, and having `Python 2.7.10`:

```
scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 48,  
in <module>
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py",    
line 10, in <module>
from scrapy.http import Request
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line   
12, in <module>
from scrapy.http.request.rpc import XmlRpcRequest
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/rpc.py",  
line 7, in <module>
from six.moves import xmlrpc_client as xmlrpclib
ImportError: cannot import name xmlrpc_client
```

But I can import module:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun 10 2015, 19:42:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scrapy
>>>
```

What's going on?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling `six`?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I've just fixed this issue on my OS X.

**Please backup your files first.**

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six*
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six*
sudo pip install six
```

Scrapy 1.0.0 is ready to go.

---

If you encounter an error `rm: /System/Library/... Operation not permitted`

Please try to disable [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)
See [Operation Not Permitted when on root El capitan (rootless disabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled)

Comment: Happened here as well. Seems exclusive to OS X

Comment: This helped me. I've uninstalled scrapy. Executed the above commands, then installed scrapy 1.0.0: `sudo pip install scrapy==1.0.0`. Thank you :)

Comment: Dude, you saved my time!

Comment: the second line throws an error saying "rm: /System/Library/... Operation not permitted" on OS X El Capitan

Comment: @rraallvv you may try to disable System Integrity Protection. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled

Answer (score 32):

This is a known issue on Mac OSX for Scrapy. You can refer to [this link](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/e645d6a01e53af35e27b47ed80cfd6f9282f50b2).

Basically the issue is with the PYTHONPATH in your system. To solve the issue change the current PYTHONPATH to point to the newer or none Mac OSX version of Python. Before running Scrapy, try:

`export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`

If that worked you can change the .bashrc file permanently:

`echo "export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" >> ~/.bashrc`

If none of this works, take a look at the link above.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same exact problem when upgrading to Scrapy 1.0. After numerous work arounds the solution that worked for me was uninstalling six with pip:

> sudo pip uninstall six

then re-installing six via easy_install

> easy_install six

Hope that works!

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution.

Comment: Using easy_install is [discouraged nowadays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install).
Upgrading with pip is better.

Answer (score 5):

Better than downgrading Scrapy it's to upgrade your version of six:

```
pip install --upgrade six scrapy
```

This will allow you to use all the goodies from Scrapy 1.0 ;)

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue. Try this:

sudo pip uninstall scrapy

sudo pip install scrapy==0.24.2

Then give it a shot

Comment: hm, it's better to upgrade six than using older Scrapy. `pip install --upgrade six` should do it.

Comment: Downgrading the package doesn't solves the issue. It gets an old package which was upgraded for a reason...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best solution on OS X should be "Don’t use system python". It will make life easier. [This link](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#mac-os-x) shows how to do this.

> There’s a known issue that prevents pip from updating system packages. This has to be addressed to successfully install Scrapy and its dependencies. Here are some proposed solutions:
>
> (Recommended) Don’t use system python, install a new, updated version that doesn’t conflict with the rest of your system. Here’s how to do it using the homebrew package manager:
>
> 1. Install homebrew following the instructions in http://brew.sh/
> 2. Update your PATH variable to state that homebrew packages should be used before system packages (Change .bashrc to .zshrc accordantly if you’re using zsh as default shell):
>
> echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
>
> 3. Reload .bashrc to ensure the changes have taken place:
>
> source ~/.bashrc
>
> 4. Install python:
>
> brew install python
>
> 5. Latest versions of python have pip bundled with them so you won’t need to install it separately. If this is not the case, upgrade python:
>
> brew update; brew upgrade python