# Scrapy error : exceptions.AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'urljoin'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have installed scrapy using pip and tried the example in the scrapy documentation.

I got the error `cannot import name xmlrpc_client`

After looking into a stachoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964836/scrapy-throws-importerror-cannot-import-name-xmlrpc-client)
i have fixed it using

```
sudo pip uninstall scrapy

sudo pip install scrapy==0.24.2
```

but now it shows me `exceptions.AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'urljoin'`

Here is my code :

```
import scrapy


class StackOverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('.question-summary h3 a::attr(href)'):
            full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_question)

    def parse_question(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.css('h1 a::text').extract()[0],
            'votes': response.css('.question .vote-count-post::text').extract()[0],
            'body': response.css('.question .post-text').extract()[0],
            'tags': response.css('.question .post-tag::text').extract(),
            'link': response.url,
        }
```

Can anyone please help me with this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*In Scrapy >=0.24.2*, `HtmlResponse` class does not yet have `urljoin()` method. Use [`urlparse.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) directly:

```
full_url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, href.extract())
```

Don't forget to import it:

```
import urlparse
```

Note that `urljoin()` alias/helper was added in Scrapy 1.0, here is the related issue:

- [Add Response.urljoin() helper](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1086)

And here is [what it actually is](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/342cb622f1ea93268477da557099010bbd72529a/scrapy/http/response/__init__.py#L81):

```
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urljoin

def urljoin(self, url):
    """Join this Response's url with a possible relative url to form an
    absolute interpretation of the latter."""
    return urljoin(self.url, url)
```

Comment: But how can the example shown in their website be wrong?
And when i tried it with urlparse,it is giving me `urljoin() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: @user3437315 the example is for Scrapy 1.0 while you are using 0.24.2

Comment: Thanks,But where can i get documentation for Scrapy 0.24.2 .It doesn't seem to be there on their website

Comment: @user3437315 try just uninstall scrapy and installing again.

Comment: I did that.i get cannot import name xmlrpc_client error!
I tried reinstalling six as well.But not working!

Answer (score 0):

The example code you're using is for scrapy 1.0. Since you've downgraded to 0.24, you need to use the `urljoin` from `urlparse`:

```
full_url = urljoin(response.url, href.extract())
```

If you click the "Scrapy 0.24 (old stable)" button above the example you'll get example code for the scrapy version you're using.