# Mac OS X El Capitan - Scrapy/Python ImportError: cannot import name xmlrpc_client

Tags: python, macos, scrapy, pip

I am trying to use Scrapy on Mac OS X El Capitan. I have zsh installed and I have tried everything that I could find online to fix this issue. I have also looked at [Scrapy throws ImportError: cannot import name xmlrpc_client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964836/scrapy-throws-importerror-cannot-import-name-xmlrpc-client) and could not resolve my problem!

Python installed via brew and added "pip install scrapy":

```
➜  DriverEBV  which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

My .zshrc has the following line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH="/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages"
```

This is the error I get:

```
➜  DriverEBV  scrapy runspider DriverEBV.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.rpc import XmlRpcRequest
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/rpc.py", line 7, in <module>
    from six.moves import xmlrpc_client as xmlrpclib
ImportError: cannot import name xmlrpc_client
```

When I run "pip install scrapy" now this is what I see:

```
➜  DriverEBV  pip install scrapy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cssselect>=0.9 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): queuelib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyOpenSSL in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): w3lib>=1.8.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Twisted>=10.0.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): service-identity in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cryptography>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): zope.interface>=3.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): characteristic>=14.0.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1-modules in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): enum34 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipaddress in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): idna>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1.0->cryptography>=0.7->pyOpenSSL->scrape)
```

Anybody able to help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy throws ImportError: cannot import name xmlrpc\_client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964836/scrapy-throws-importerror-cannot-import-name-xmlrpc-client)

Comment: Unfortunately not a duplicate. I have tried everything discussed in the article you have posted. So have I tried pretty much everything else that was available online going from least intrusive to most intrusive.

Comment: why do you set the python path here?

Comment: The idea there was to add Python with pip in my user to be separate from Mac OS native pip and to install scrapy with --user.

Comment: Are you sure your .zshrc got sourced? If you specifically type: `export PYTHONPATH="/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages"` in your terminal followed by a simple `scrapy shell http://stackoverflow.com` do you still get the error?

Comment: @JackMurphy I had to reinstall lxml, six, and setuptools to get everything working properly

Answer (score 2):

I've had nothing but pain mucking with the Mac OS X system Python libraries installed in the `/Library/Python` directory. What has worked well for me is a combination of MacPorts and virtualenv:

1. Install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php)
2. Install Python, pip, and virtualenv from MacPorts:

   ```
   /opt/local/bin/port install python27
   /opt/local/bin/port install py27-pip
   /opt/local/bin/port install py27-virtualenv
   ```
3. Setup virtualenv:

   ```
   /opt/local/bin/virtualenv-2.7 myenv
   ```
4. Activate virtualenv (don't forget the dot!)

   ```
   . myenv/bin/activate
   ```
5. Install scrapy

   ```
   pip install scrapy
   ```

This way, the system Python libraries are untouched and you can install whatever packages you like without having to remove or upgrade existing packages.

Comment: I think that solved my problem when running scrapy on the command line. when running in PyCharm, then I get this error. Any suggestions to solve?

Comment: PyCharm appears to have support for virtualenv now.  You should be able to [add an existing virtualenv](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html) via the [Project Interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/project-interpreter.html).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I figured that after posting this comment. Thanks for the information above, awarded you bounty

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was to *uninstall six and scrapy and then install again*:

```
pip uninstall six
pip uninstall scrapy

pip install six
pip install scrapy
```

Run with `sudo` if necessary.

---

Or, you can also try upgrading six and scrapy:

```
pip install --upgrade scrapy
pip install --upgrade six
```

Comment: I think that solved my problem when running scrapy on the command line. when running in PyCharm, then I get this error. Any suggestions to solve?

Comment: @GuyDaher Is the Project Interpreter in the settings the correct one? (I believe in this example it should be the default python installation)

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling via pip and then reinstall using easy_install command. I had the same trouble with another python module and doing it this way fixed the issue for me on Mac OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the best solution on OS X should be "Don’t use system python". It will make life easier. [This link](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#mac-os-x) shows how to do this.

> There’s a known issue that prevents pip from updating system packages. This has to be addressed to successfully install Scrapy and its dependencies. Here are some proposed solutions:
>
> (Recommended) Don’t use system python, install a new, updated version that doesn’t conflict with the rest of your system. Here’s how to do it using the homebrew package manager:
>
> 1. Install homebrew following the instructions in http://brew.sh/
> 2. Update your PATH variable to state that homebrew packages should be used before system packages (Change .bashrc to .zshrc accordantly if you’re using zsh as default shell):
>
> echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
>
> 3. Reload .bashrc to ensure the changes have taken place:
>
> source ~/.bashrc
>
> 4. Install python:
>
> brew install python
>
> 5. Latest versions of python have pip bundled with them so you won’t need to install it separately. If this is not the case, upgrade python:
>
> brew update; brew upgrade python

Comment: Can you then install and import "Scrapy" using this method?