# MacPorts pip install links .so file to wrong python executable on MacOS 10.11

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, macports

I am using MacOS 10.11 and in addition to the native Python installation I have installed Python and Pip through MacPorts. `python` and `pip` are linked against the respective MacPorts versions.

However, when installing a package via

```
sudo pip install <my-package>
```

a specific `.so` file of that package is linked against the native Python executable. More precisely the output of `otool -L` on that `.so` file is

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.5)
```

whereas the MacPorts version of Python resides at

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
```

How can I force Pip to use the correct Python version to link against?

Comment: Probably best to setup a virtual environment.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37128342/6084928).

Comment: @LexScarisbrick : Thanks for the link! However, when installing the package in the virtual environment, the .so file is still linked against the native system python. Do I have to modify any configs prior to calling pip in the virtual environment?

Comment: Interesting.  Which package and where can it be fetched?  If the package isn't publicly available, does the `setup.py` in the package have a [shebang](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1530702/6084928)?

Comment: It is publicly available from PyPi. It is the nupic package. When calling pip install nupic, it also installs the package nupic.bindings. Therein is the nupic/bindings/_math.so file which is linked against the incorrect python distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is: you can't.

It's not a problem with pip.  The `nupic` package relies on the `nupic.bindings` package, which contains the `_math.so` you note, and it's currently distributed via PyPI as binary-only:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nupic.bindings

You can compile your own `nupic.bindings` package, but the build process looks fairly involved, which is probably why they distribute binary-only:

https://github.com/numenta/nupic.core

Good luck!