# Scrapy ImportError: cannot import name xmlrpc_client

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrape on Mac OS X EI, and I have successfully installed scrapy using

```
pip install scrapy
```

in the terminal.
After that, I met the above problem when I tried to "import scrapy" in the Pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ziyuan/PycharmProjects/untitled/en.py", line 1, in <module>
import scrape
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from scrapy.http import Request
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from scrapy.http.request.rpc import XmlRpcRequest
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/rpc.py", line 7, in <module>
from six.moves import xmlrpc_client as xmlrpclib
ImportError: cannot import name xmlrpc_client
```

And I have tried everything from [Scrapy throws ImportError: cannot import name xmlrpc_client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964836/scrapy-throws-importerror-cannot-import-name-xmlrpc-client)

Specifically, when I tried the highest-voted solution, the second line

```
sudo rm -rf/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six*
```

throwed me another problem:

```
rm: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info: Operation not permitted
rm: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.py: Operation not permitted
rm: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc: Operation not permitted
```

What should I do now? I have searched it in google for a long time and I really have no idea now.

Comment: That last `rm` issue is probably caused by El Capitan's SIP "feature". Disabling it should allow you to the files, but I am not sure that'd help in your original problem.

Comment: that is a system integrity protect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659348/operation-not-permitted-when-on-root-el-capitan-rootless-disabled

Answer (score 1):

A different way to deal with this problem, rather than highest-voted solution as you mentioned, is using `other Python`(not the system one) and `virtualenv`.

But why `new Python`? [Here's an good article](https://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/) for the question. Reasons are easy to find.

And why `virtualenv`? You can get the point form [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Furthermore, it's maybe not an good idea to use `$ sudo pip (...)`. Please look at [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1668).

So let's do the [recommended way](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html) by one of Scrapy's contributor! Look at Mac OS X part: Using Homebrew to install new Python, updated your path variable, ...etc. Although she said using `virtualenv` is optional, I can only keep `ImportError: blahblah..` away in my own virtual environment when using Scrapy.

Answer (score 1):

After trying several solutions and attempting to work around the six 1.4.1 version, I found this worked:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade six
```

Comment: Edit your answer — code into code tags. As a side note, this may be better placed in the comments box — I don't think it is a concise answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`Operation not permited` means you don't have the permission to remove this. Try `sudo rm` instead to delete it as a Super User.

Though ideally you shouldn't `rm` anything from your python, try `pip uninstall six` instead. However you still need `six` so you might as well try upgrading it via `pip install six --upgrade`.

Note that you might have to use `pip2` instead of `pip` because certain systems label it differently.

Comment: El Capitan adds a feature where root doesn't have permission to modify /System, /bin, /etc, /usr (except /usr/local)