# pip doesn't find a package listed in pypi.python.org

Tags: python, package, pip

I'm trying to install the [Stoner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Stoner) package viv `pip` under Python v2.7.6 (default in Ubuntu 14.04). I use:

```
pip install --user Stoner
```

as I've done with countless other packages, but I get:

```
Downloading/unpacking Stoner
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Stoner
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for Stoner
Storing debug log for failure in /home/gabriel/.pip/pip.log
```

Here's the full [pip.log](https://upl.io/443ql1) file. What's going on? Why can't that package be found?

Comment: Have you tried using `easy_install` as their documentation recommends?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @jonrsharpe no I have not as `easy_install` is no longer the recommended way to install packages: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30408520/1391441

Comment: @AbuAshrafMasnun, I forgot to mention that. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: This is true, but: 1. you've tried `pip` and failed; and 2. it's what the maintainers suggest using. They're not distributing wheels.

Comment: `easy_install` fails with `ImportError: No module named Cython.Build` which is odd since it is not one of the required packages listed in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Stoner (unless I'm missing something): `numpy >=1.8, scipy >=0.14, matplotlib >=1.4, h5py, numba and lmfit`.