# Should I install my Python application with setuptools?

Tags: python, deployment, setuptools

I am currently about to deploy my Python application. I used to think that the only good way to install the pure Python app is to just copy the source code files along with the requirements file, and install packages listed in the requirements file (also, [Python onbuild Docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/3.5/onbuild/Dockerfile) does suppose this way).

But I can see that folks often install their apps using setuptools like `./setup.py install`(it seems that [Warehouse project](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse) does this, for example).

Which of the two is considered a better practice?

What are the benefits from installing your app as a package?

Comment: Using `pip` to install packages is useful for [a lot of different reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install) and is the ideal way to install and manage Python packages.

Comment: @sytech Yes, I like to use `pip` as front-end tool for installation. But my question is about, if I should make my app (not library!) a valid package, and, in terms of `pip`, install it with `pip install .` during deployment process. Sorry for being unclear.