# fedora "easy_install3": command not found

Tags: python, fedora, easy-install

I use python3.6 on my fedora 26
I tried to use `easy_install3` but the command is not found.
I did :

```
sudo dnf reinstall python3-setuptools python3-pip python3-lxml
```

But nothing was changed.

Could you please help me.

Many thank's

Comment: [You should really be using pip instead of easy_install.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220404/744178)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly install from [PYPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)

```
$ pip install setuptools
```

You can even do one better. Clone from the pypa/setuptools repository (https://github.com/pypa/setuptools) and run `setup.py`

```
$ git clone https://github.com/pypa/setuptools
$ cd setuptools
$ python setup.py install
```

This should help

Answer (score 0):

It's very old but I try to answer this because it might be help for others.

Basically, *don't use pip* as much as possible in Fedora and other Linux distributions which may provide what you want as a package (rpm or deb or ...) and the ones installed with pip might conflict with others and hard to maintain.

Some distributions may have some utilities to find out what packages can provide what you want to use. In fedora, 'dnf provides' is that, for example, you can find what packages provide '/usr/bin/easy_install*' like this:

```
$ sudo dnf provides '/usr/bin/easy_install*'
    ... (snip) ...
python2-setuptools-40.8.0-1.fc29.noarch : Easily build and distribute Python packages
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/easy_install
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7

python3-setuptools-40.8.0-1.fc29.noarch : Easily build and distribute Python 3 packages
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/easy_install-3.7
    ... (snip) ...
$
```

In this example, it turns out that easy_install-3.7 is provided by the package 'python3-setuptools' and there is no package provide '/usr/bin/easy_install3'.