# Configuring easy_install path.

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services

Following images show the error and my environment variables
[image]

[image]

Comment: path is fine. Open a new command prompt it should work

Comment: I did it a lot of time.I also restarted the system

Comment: Please change `c:\python32\tools\Scripts` to c:\python32\Scripts and it open a new terminal and it should work for you .
also navigate  to c:\python32\Scripts folder and check if easy_install exists or not

Comment: First one my scripts folder exist within tools\scripts

Comment: second yes easy_install exist within Scripts folder. And I also restarted CLI as well as system.

Comment: can you open command prompt and try this 
set path=%path%;c:\python32\tools\Scripts\;c:\python32

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but is there a specific requirement that you need to use easy_install? You could try using pip. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install