# Django installation fails using Ansible in RHEL

Tags: python, django, ansible, rhel

I have the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: app
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install MySQL-Python
      yum: name=MySQL-python state=present

    - name: Install Python Setup Tools
      yum: name=python-setuptools state=present

    - name: Install django
      easy_install: name=django state=present
```

This fails with the error:

> This version of Django requires Python 3.4, but you're trying to\ninstall it on Python 2.7.\n\nThis may be because you are using a version of pip that doesn't\nunderstand the python_requires classifier. Make sure you\nhave pip >= 9.0 and setuptools >= 24.2, then try again:\n\n    $ python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools\n    $ python -m pip install django\n\nThis will install the latest version of Django which works on your\nversion of Python. If you can't upgrade your pip (or Python), request\nan older version of Django:\n\n    $ python -m pip install \"django<2\"\nerror: Setup script exited with 1\n"}

I followed [this article](https://www.tecmint.com/install-python-in-linux/) to install Python 3 and also set `python=python3`, yet I am facing the same error message when I run the playbook.

Can anyone please suggest what to do? Also, I do I install a previous version of Django using Ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [pip module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/pip_module.html) to install Django instead of `easy_install`. You can use `executable` to use the `pip` for Python 3.4. You can use `version` to specify which version you want to use - if you decide to use Python 2 you will need to install `Django<2`.

```
- name: Install django
  pip: 
    name: django
    executable: pip-3.4
    version: 2.0.4
```

Note that `MySQL-Python` has not been supported in several years. It would be better to use the fork `mysqlclient`, which supports Python 3.

You should also consider installing your modules in a virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I actually modified easy_install: name=django state=present to  easy_install: name=django<2 state=present and it solved the issue.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but I would consider switching to `pip` - the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) describes `pip` as the preferred installer program. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install) for more info.