# ImportError: No module named cloud even though google-cloud for python is installed

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I installed google-cloud for python by using the following command:

```
sudo easy_install google-cloud
```

The client got installed sucessfully, but now when I run the script it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "coreAPI.py", line 8, in <module>
        from google.cloud import bigquery
ImportError: No module named cloud
```

Why does this error occur? Isn't easy install meant to install the cloud module?

Comment: Try installing using `PIP` instead of `easy_install`. `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) explaining that you should run the following command `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery` to install the Python BigQuery client library. There's also an example at the bottom of the page on how to call the library.