# Installing BeautifulSoup on Mac OSX

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have tried everything here: [How can I install the Beautiful Soup module on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452283/how-can-i-install-the-beautiful-soup-module-on-the-mac)

Installation seems to work (getting correct output during install) from both the traditional way to install and also using easy_install but when I use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

the interpreter says no such module exists.

What should I look at first to troubleshoot this?

Comment: are you sure that you use the correct version of python interpreter (if several are installed on your computer)? try calling your script with python2.6, python2.7, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see all the packages you have installed, you can run the following in a interpreter:

```
>>> help('modules')
```

That will list for you all the modules you have installed. Look for `bs4` in the list (which seems to be alphabetical). Another option is to issue at your prompt:

```
$ python -c "help('modules')" | grep bs4
```

If nothing comes up, or you cannot find it in the list, the module is not installed.

To install it, I used `sudo pip install bs4`. You may need to run `sudo easy_install pip` first to get `pip`. Also note the use of `sudo`, as this may make a difference.

And I'm running 10.8 build version 12C60.

Comment: Thank you - very useful. I can confirm that the module is installed and for some reason it is allowing me to import it now. Very strange. For some reason after I install new modules (among other things) my machine won't update. I let the machine 'sleep' and when I come back to it they are working. Is there some sort of 'update' command or refresh that must be done after installing new packages?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can always run the `help()` command after an install to make sure it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have an uggly solutions which works for me:

```
try:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
except ImportError:
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
```

after what, I call everything with `bs` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. bs4 is installed but it wasn't showing up in help(modules).

I don't know if this will work for others, but I had the same issue with openCV and solved it by adding the following before trying to load the package. It worked for openCV and it just worked for bs4:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
```