# ImportError: No module named bs4 on mac

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, importerror

I sat down tonight and have decided to leran how to use python. Inspired by this webpage scraping article. 
cam.ly/danesblog/2011/01/craigslist-arbitrage/

after working through a tutorial I:

1) downloaded and installed python:   http://www.python.org/getit/  first 3.3 then 2.7

2) downloaded bs4:   www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/

3) followed Brian Clapper's instructions:
[How can I install the Beautiful Soup module on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452283/how-can-i-install-the-beautiful-soup-module-on-the-mac)

- tried both easy_install and python setup.py install methods

I am still getting "ImportError: No module named bs4"

Python is installed in applications folder,  the bs4 package auto installs in Library 
Is this the problem? I tried copying and moving the folder into Python application, but didn't work.

I have also tried both forms:

- from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
- from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Thank you for the support.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is Python code in its entirety. Put the directory in your `site-packages` directory or somewhere else on your Python path and be done with it.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct version of Python (or easy_install) - eg: make sure you're attempting to run the Python that you've used to install the package

Comment: Yes, if you installed python.org Pythons, you'll also need to install versions of `easy_install` for each of them.  Otherwise, you are likely using the Apple-supplied `easy_install` commands which will install to the system Pythons instead.  See  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions

Comment: I found site-packages with help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory,   and just copied the installed bs4 files in there. I had to change, back to python 2.7 because even though I was downloading beautifulsoup 4-4.1.3 one of the files still had python 2 format of "print." Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I know considerably more now than I did 48 hours ago

Answer (score -2):

The solution is in setting up the PATH the packages get installed. EPD or Canopy create their VirtualEnv set up in the `.\~profile` and `.\~bash_profile` files. These path may not be identical to the path pip install or easy_install try to install the packages. If you open bash_profile or profile files there should be a path similar to this :

```
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /Users/test_user/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```

I am using Enthought as my python editor so yours will be something else but what is important is if you are using pip or easy_install the address the python packages are installed should point here. Or put another way, your active virtual environment set up is in this address.

Comment: This hardly qualifies as a best practice.