# ModuleNotFoundError: no module named bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I had install Jupyter follow this guide: https://medium.com/@blessedmarcel1/how-to-install-jupyter-notebook-on-mac-using-homebrew-528c39fd530f

I installed the version of python 3.7.5, and then I followed the command

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

but on the notebook continue to come out the error after I wrote

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Comment: can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29052608/2498251

Answer (score 2):

You installed beautifulsoup4 not `bs4`

Follow this code to get what you are requiring:

```
pip3 install bs4 # for Py3
```

It maybe that the pip needs upgrading to be compatible with Python 3 version:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

then try running the first command.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Comment: No Java runtime present, requesting install.
Maybe is this the problem?

Comment: this should be independent of java runtime, check the pip --version you are running, it may need updating. see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079941/importerror-no-module-named-bs4-on-mac) it's for mac.